# GNU indent: which option puts function return type same line

Tags: c, code-formatting, gnu-indent

Using GNU `indent`, when I used `gnu` style, I will end up with a source like this:

```
void
compute_column_indices(u32 size, s32 * ind)
{
    ...
}
```

But I don't want the return value (void) to sit on its own line. The `linux` style does it but it introduces other style aspects I don't like.

This is what I want to have done:

```
void compute_column_indices(u32 size, s32 * ind)
{
    ...
}
```

What switch to use to accomplish this? I stared at the man page and I can't find it.

Comment: That's a neat little utility... but wow there's a lot of options. But I'm glad I now know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Argh, I found it! It is `--procnames-start-lines` option (or `-psl` for short).

Comment: The `-psl` option causes return types to go on their own line.  To get them on the same line as your question indicates, you need its negation: `-npsl`.